# Custom launcher app icon issue?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-launcher, image-scaling

I got all list of installed applications with details **(app_name ,app package_name,app_icon).**

I attached **Screenshots** ,which display what issue i still facing.

[image: Screenshot-1]

[image: screenshot-2]

**This is my code**

1. [App List Adapter JAVA](https://github.com/ArbazGitHub/Custom-Launcher/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/techno/minilauncher/adapter/CustomAppListAdapter.java)
2. [App List Cell_layout XML](https://github.com/ArbazGitHub/Custom-Launcher/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/app_list_row.xml) ,in XMl i also set imageView scalType but its not working.
3. [App List Activity JAVA](https://github.com/ArbazGitHub/Custom-Launcher/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/techno/minilauncher/screens/AppListActivity.java)

Comment: I think issue in android manifest file.

Comment: i provide my manifest file check it any thing missing.

Comment: there is no issue! from where I m looking at it! there you have wrap content for both height and width ! my best guess here I can is the size of images you have there is not ok! for some icons are making them like this!

Comment: may be shadow and invisible background space is causing the spacing issue! check your icon images in any photoshop tool

Comment: @Rizwanatta  how can i get and open  that app icon which i mention on the screensorts in photoshop?

Comment: so those are icons of already installed apps!  sorry I took it wrong for that!  for now just make your App List Cell_layout XML  for imageView fixed size (50dp,50dp) instead of wrap_content for now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so those are icons of already installed apps! for now just make your App List Cell_layout XML for imageView fixed size (~50dp,~50dp) instead of wrap_content

for now do this!  it should solve the issue for now ok!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAppIcon"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAppLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxEms="10"
                android:text="--"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **Yes**  its work  i set iamgeView 
   android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"

**Thanks**

Comment: accept the answer please so that It could help other people too! welcome @Arbaz.in

Comment: Please  suggest me if i forgot to put any other file  in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check It..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adruser.annotationdemo">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".interfaceclass.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".interfaceclass.SecondActivity"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please explain whats wrong with my manifest file?
i put this line in to android manifest for set activity as a home activity  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

Comment: home is referred to  ADW Launcher, and LAUNCHER refer is used to specify which of your activities can be launched.

Comment: Yes, you are right ,but i want to launch my android activity as a HOME launcher